# WebStorm clickable source files from npm commands like lint

Tags: npm, webstorm, eslint

Is it possible to make source files clickable from eslint output?

[image]

**EDIT:**
Clicking PerfomanceActions.js does nothing.

Comment: Hmm? Please explain. As far as I see from your screenshot the `PerformanceActions.js` file should be clickable...

Comment: Exactly you would expect that but it doesn't, clicking it does nothing.

Comment: What IDE version do you use there? Is that file part of the project or outside of it? Maybe it's in a folder that is excluded? Do you have any 3rd party (not bundled) plugins installed? if so -- any difference if you disable them? I'm not using nmp like that (only for installing stuff globally) but such links do work for me in Gulp/Phing/PHPUnit consoles -- *in theory* it should not behave any differently...

Comment: @LazyOne Its latest version of webstorm (2016.1) I don't have any additional plugins that effect terminal. All this is doing is running npm lint which runs eslint and spits out errors if found with path to source but that path isn't clickable even though it looks like it should be.

Comment: what does the command look like? Please provide the snippet from your package.json

Comment: @lena It's nothing special, it's just `eslint ./src`

Comment: but eslint output doesn't include file names/paths.. You must be doing something special to make them printed to stdout?

Comment: just tried "lint": "eslint -f unix ./src" - links are clickable

Comment: @lena adding `-f unix` did work but messed up original format :(